# Launch an activity when alarm is triggered

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-alarms

**1)** I need to launch an activity when the alarm triggers , I tried add the activity when in the onRecieve event of BroadCastReceiver but its failing.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Recieved!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Activity act = new Activity();
    act.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

**Error:**

```
06-22 13:42:00.733: W/dalvikvm(750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.exercise.AndroidTime.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.exercise.AndroidTime.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:23)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-22 13:42:00.763: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  ... 10 more
```

---

**2)** How do I make an activity keep running even though the back button is pressed. Activity will close when certain criteria in the source code is met. Such as the alarm will not go off and he cant close the app also until user answers a question correctly.

Comment: It says application has stopped unexpectedly. Force Close!

Comment: yeah...you need to be more precise. paste your logcat error

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah put your whole receiver code here and give more description and logcat also.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Added the code and logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write below Code into your BroadcastReceiver class.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("your package name", "your package name.your activity name");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

instead of

```
Activity act = new Activity();
act.startActivity(intent);
```

Define Receiver class into your androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="de.vogella.android.mybroadcast" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Ya its done now.. If i remove the above part and just add the toast message then toast message shows up. But how do i trigger an activity when the alarm fires

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12901/discussion-between-chandu-indyaah-and-dipak-keshariya)

Comment: I would rather use intent.setClass(context, SomeClass.class);

Answer (score 2):

As for the second part, override the BackButton by

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //do nothing or whatever you would want to display
    return;

}
```

To override the Menu and the Home button, use the following code..

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the Home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
            return true; // event has been handled
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the Menu button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            return true; // tell your phone that you have handled the event
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Well, not exactly. I have edited my answer to include the Home button and the Menu button overriding. Please check that.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your onReceive Method

```
Intent intent;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
       Toast.makeText(context, "Recieved!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(context, Test.class); //Test is a dummy class name where to redirect
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       intent.putExtra("msg", str);
       context.startActivity(intent);
}
```